# Python - Compare two lists in a comprehension

Tags: list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm trying to understand how comprehensions work.

I would like to loop through two lists, and compare each to find differences.
If one/or-more word(s) is different, I would like to print this word(s).

**I'd like this all in one nice line of code,  which is why I'm interested in comprehensions.**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like kriegar suggested using sets is probably the easiest solution. If you absolutely need to use list comprehension, I'd use something like this:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list_2 = [1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6]

# Print all items from list_1 that are not in list_2 ()
print(*[item for item in list_1 if item not in list_2], sep='\n')

# Print all items from list_1 that differ from the item at the same index in list_2
print(*[x for x, y in zip(list_1, list_2) if x != y], sep='\n')

# Print all items from list_2 that differ from the item at the same index in list_1
print(*[y for x, y in zip(list_1, list_2) if x != y], sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 21):

Doing it in "one nice line of code" is code golf, and misguided. Make it readable instead.

```
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    if a != b:
       print(a, "is different from", b)
```

This is not different in any significant way from this:

```
[print(a, "is different from", b) for a, b in zip(list1, list2) if a!=b]
```

Except that the expanded version easier to read and understand than the comprehension.

Comment: i do agree, it is easier to read but I've been doing this way for some time and im gettig bored of it .. not the zip method tho, thanks for showing me that. If these a shorter way ... I might aswel learn it ... might come in handy

Comment: No, there isn't a shorter way to do this comparison. The other solutions have a different view of what "difference" is. Which is right depends on you. Being bored with writing good code might not be a good reason. ;)

Comment: As someone learning Python this week, I appreciate your answer and the clarity of your code.  Good stuff!

Comment: This works well if both the lists are of same size. What if the list a is very large than list b?

Comment: The 2nd code snippet is significantly different in that it builds a pointless lists of `None` values returned by the print calls- this is unpythonic, list comphrensions are for building lists and not procedral calls

Answer (score 5):

If you want to compare two lists for differences, I think you want to use a [**`set`**](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html).

```
s.symmetric_difference(t)   s ^ t   new set with elements in either s or t but not both
```

example:

```
>>> L1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> L2 = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] 
>>> S1 = set(L1)
>>> S2 = set(L2)
>>> difference = list(S1.symmetric_difference(S2))
>>> print difference
['a', 'e']
>>>
```

one-line form?

```
>>> print list(set(L1).symmetric_difference(set(L2)))
['a', 'e']
>>>
```

if you really want to use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [word for word in L1 if word not in L2] + [word for word in L2 if word not in L1]
['a', 'e']
```

much less efficient as the size of the lists grow.

Comment: this is a great suggestion and I will defiantly use it. But in my quest to learn more about comprehensions I gots to give my little tick to überjesus ... unless i can give more than one, haven't tried that

Comment: My understanding is that elements can repeat and the order is important. This way the usage of `set` does not produce correct results.